# Pythonのpandasを用いて、特定のセルとその後ろの複数行(列が異なる)を用いた条件から、新たな列を作成する方法

Tags: python, pandas

1分毎に、OP、HP、LP、CP、A、Bの値を取ったデータがあります。
(列BはAが3以上となる場合を1、そうでない場合は0としている列です)

ここで、Bが1となる時のCPの値からLPがn分以内に2000以上下がる時にTrue、そうでない場合をFalseとするような列Cを作ろうと思いました。

作成したコードは以下の通りです。(ohlcと言う名前のcsvからデータを読み込んでいます。このcsvファイルは https://free.filesend.to/filedn_infoindex?rp=1da6d667519e74efb78c8265cedb405o からダウンロードできます)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n=10
margin=2000

df=pd.read_csv('ohlc', header=0)
Bsum=df['B'].sum()

for i in range(1,n):
  df['C']=False
  for j in range(1,i+1):
    df['C']=df['C']|(df['CP']-df['LP'].shift(-i)>=margin)
  df['C']=df['C']&df['B']

  print("C/B n="+str(i)+": "+str(df['C'].sum()/Bsum))
```

コードでは、Bが1となる時に、列Cが1(True)となる割合をnの数値ごとに画面に出力しています。
この割合は、nの値が増えるごとに増えていくはずです。
(6分以内に2000以上下がる場合の数より、7分以内に2000以上下がる場合の数の方が多くなるはず)

しかし、n=10で試してみると、

```
C/B n=5: 0.271777003484
C/B n=6: 0.289198606272
C/B n=7: 0.271777003484
```

となり、n=6からn=7にかけ減少していて、意図した結果になっていません。

このコードは何が間違っているのでしょうか？
また、より効率の良いコードにするための案(例えば、二番目のforループはpandsの機能を用いれば実は無くせるなど)がありましたら、ご教示頂けると有り難いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

結果が意図したものになっていない理由は

```
for i in range(1,n):
    df['C']=False
    # ...略
```

と **'C列'** の値をループ毎に初期化していることが原因かと思われまので
この部分を

```
df['C']=False
for i in range(1,n):
    # ...略
```

のように修正するとよいのではないでしょうか。

---

次に、より効率のよい方法ですが、

現在 for文にて処理している箇所は `rolling().min()` を使用して

```
df['CX'] = ((df.CP-df.LP.rolling(n).min().shift(-(n-1))) >= margin) & df.B
```

のように書き換えることができます。

Comment: 回答有り難うございます。すみません 。説明が足りていなかったです。外側のループは動作の検証のためのなので、毎回Falseで初期化しても正しく動作するはずなんです。・・・とよく見たら、最も内側の`df['C']=df['C']|(df['CP']-df['LP'].shift(-i)>=margin)`が`j`ではなく、`i`にしたままというしょーもないミスで動作がおかしくなっていた事に今気づきました。お騒がせしました。

Comment: 回答の後半部分のrollingの部分、物凄く助かります。まさしくこういうものを求めていました。有り難うございます。